# Downloaded MP3 File Opens Wrong App

Tags: downloading, default-applications, mp3

I downloaded an audio file (a podcast, 41MB, .mp3). After it downloaded, I tried playing the file by selecting the file via the pull-down menu. I also tried by opening up the Downloads app and selecting the file (not long-pressing). Both of these methods opened the .mp3 file in the [c:geo](http://www.cgeo.org) Geocaching app, which treated my action as Importing a Geocache map file (Geocaching is a GPS-based scavenger hunt or letter-box game). c:geo opened up its List feature, which is used for storing and sorting Lists of Geocaches, which you would usually store by Location.

I tried to prevent this behavior by looking in the Google Music, Downloads and c:geo application Defaults, to determine whether there was something I could do there (i.e. clear some setting that allowed c:geo to open .mp3 files by default). This may be part of the solution, but I did not succeed.

Does anyone know a straight-forward method to open and *play* downloaded .mp3 files? The ideal solution would utilize Google Play Music, but that's not a requirement; *not* deleting the c:geo app would also be preferred.

The device is an LG Nexus 5, but I'm not tagging the question with that info since I doubt it is device-specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One fairly simple work-around is to upload the .mp3 file to Google Drive. Google Drive provides its own basic interface for playing .mp3 files from the app. This is not ideal, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Although annoying at first, try resetting default apps for everything. You will need to select Always for usual apps like your browser etc.

Settings->Apps in the 3 dot menu should be "Reset App Preferences"

Comment: This didn't work but thank you for the suggestion.